# Takes too long to export data from bigquery into Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

In the Jupyter Notebook, I am trying to import data from BigQuery using an sql-like query on the BigQuery server. I then store the data in a dataframe:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="credentials.json"
from google.cloud import bigquery

sql = """
SELECT * FROM dataset.table
"""
client = bigquery.Client()
df_bq = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

The data has the shape (6000000, 8) and uses about 350MB of memory once stored in the dataframe.

The query `sql`, if executed directly in BQ, takes about 2 seconds.

However, it usually takes about 30-40 minutes to execute the code above, and more often than not the code fails to execute raising the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')",))
```

All in all, there could be three reasons for the error:

1. It takes the BigQuery server a long time to execute the query
2. It takes a long time to transfer data (I don't understand why a 350MB file should take 30min to be sent over the network. I tried using a LAN connection to eliminate server cuts and maximize throughput, which didn't help)
3. It takes a long time to set a dataframe with the data from BigQuery

Would be happy to gain any insight into the problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: 40 mins seems a lot indeed...maybe it's the http transport layer. I wonder if you can make two tests: first, what happens if you set a limit to 10000 rows for instance in your query? Is it still slow? Also, can you test first exporting this data to GCS gizzed and then bring it to host to finally read as dataframe, is it still slow?

Comment: There is now official Google Documentation around setting up BigQuery in Jupyter. Documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter I have recently set this up having followed the guide with no issues. Regarding runtime it is similar to running it in BigQuery within the Google Cloud Platform, potentially slower by some fractions of a second, likely due to authentication methods.

Answer (score 16):

**Use bigquery storage** to get large data queries from bigquery into a pandas dataframe really fast.

**Working code snippet:**

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage

# uncomment this part if you are working locally
# import os
# os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="your_json_key.json"

# Explicitly create a credentials object. This allows you to use the same
# credentials for both the BigQuery and BigQuery Storage clients, avoiding
# unnecessary API calls to fetch duplicate authentication tokens.
credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
)

# Make clients.
bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=your_project_id,)
bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient(credentials=credentials)

# define your query
your_query = """select * from your_big_query_table"""

# set you bqstorage_client as argument in the to_dataframe() method.
# i've also added the tqdm progress bar here so you get better insight
# into how long it's still going to take
dataframe = (
    bqclient.query(your_query)
            .result()
            .to_dataframe(
                bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient,
                progress_bar_type='tqdm_notebook',)
)
```

**You can find more on how to use bigquery storage here:**
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Try using BigQuery Storage API - it's blazing fast for downloading large tables as pandas dataframes

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas

Answer (score 0):

The [WSAETIMEDOUT](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2960) error means that the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. You need to review your firewall.

Regarding:

1. the query takes 2 seconds as you tested
2. review your firewall
3. as your data shape is (6000000, 8), this will take time depending on the computing resources you are using

This being said, you might reach the connection time out because the multidimensional array takes too long.

You can separate the query and the dataframe and print the time to have a better view of what is happening.

```
    result = client.query(sql)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    df_bq = result.to_dataframe()
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't help, maybe write the file out to GCS from BQ and then copy to your server from there.

Alternatively you could run your notebook on a GCE VM and make the most of Google's bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method.

```
%%bigquery

SELECT * FROM table.name
```

For more detailed explanation, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter

Comment: Thank you for the edit Tripleee. I will improve my formatting in upcoming days

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).